# Unselect cell in slickgrid when grid looses focus

Tags: slickgrid

When you have clicked inside a Slickgrid, there is a currently selected cell (css class `active`). 
If you then click outside the grid, the cell is still marked as selected.

How do I unselect the cell when the user clicks outside the grid?

I have not been able to find any setting for this. There doesn't seem to be any appropriate event for the grid loosing focus either.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `grid.resetActiveCell();`.

Comment: To whoever flagged this: if you feel that it is inaccurate then please post your concerns in a comment.  By all appearances it is a valid attempt to answer the question, so please do not falsely flag it as a non-answer.